# Changing sqlite to pg

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

Could anyone help me with my problem this is my first draft website?

my new question: [How come my code and postgres are not connecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57618678/how-come-my-code-and-postgres-are-not-connecting)

I have tried of StackOverflow solutions but it just seems like I keep running into errors

This is my `database.yml`:

```
default: &default
adapter: postgresql
pool: 5
timeout: 5000

development:
    adapter: postgresql
    encoding: unicode
    database: blog_development
    pool: 5
    username: opeodumakin
    password: 6391
    port: 3000
    host: localhost

test:
    adapter: postgresql
    encoding: unicode
    database: blog_development
    pool: 5
    username: opeodumakin
    password: 6391


production:
    <<: *default
    database: db/production.sqlite3
```

I keep getting this error

vendor/cache/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:1013:in `retrieve_connection'
vendor/cache/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:118:in`retrieve_connection'
vendor/cache/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:90:in `connection'
vendor/cache/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:554:in`call'
vendor/cache/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
vendor/cache/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:98:in`run_callbacks'
vendor/cache/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
vendor/cache/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in`call'
vendor/cache/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:61:in `call'
vendor/cache/gems/web-console-3.7.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in`call_app'
vendor/cache/gems/web-console-3.7.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:30:in `block in call'
vendor/cache/gems/web-console-3.7.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in`catch'
vendor/cache/gems/web-console-3.7.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `call'
vendor/cache/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in`call'
vendor/cache/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
vendor/cache/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in`block in call'
vendor/cache/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `block in tagged'
vendor/cache/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in`tagged'
vendor/cache/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `tagged'
vendor/cache/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in`call'
vendor/cache/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
vendor/cache/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in`call'
vendor/cache/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
vendor/cache/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in`call'
vendor/cache/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
vendor/cache/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in`call'
vendor/cache/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
vendor/cache/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:127:in`call'
vendor/cache/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
vendor/cache/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:524:in`call'
vendor/cache/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/configuration.rb:227:in `call'
vendor/cache/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/server.rb:660:in`handle_request'
vendor/cache/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/server.rb:474:in `process_client'
vendor/cache/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/server.rb:334:in`block in run'
vendor/cache/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:135:in `block in spawn_thread'

Comment: Did you add `gem pg` in Gemfile??

Comment: yes i did add gem pg

Comment: Is that formatting reflective of your actual file? Indentation matters in yaml.

Comment: i believe i formatting properly and its giving me a new error AdapterNotSpecified: 'development' database is not configured. Available: ["default", "adapter", "pool", "timeout"]

Comment: It's the yml indentation issue, `adapter`, `pool`, and `timeout` should be indented under `default`.

Comment: What's the error, the "whole error" you get.

Comment: Please add the complete error you get to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. ADD

   ```
   gem 'pg', '0.18.3'
   ```
2. Update your database.yml

   ```
   connection: &connection
     adapter: postgresql
     host: <%= ENV.fetch('DB_1_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR', 'localhost') %>
     port: <%= ENV.fetch('DB_1_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT', '5432') %>
     username: postgres
     password: postgres
     pool: 5
     timeout: 5000

   development:
     <<: *connection
     database: development_db_name
   test:
     <<: *connection
     database: test_db_name

   production:
     <<: *connection
     database: production_db_name
   ```
3. Restart your server

Comment: is this corect indentation because i am getting ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished
No connection pool with 'primary' found.
Extracted source (around line #1013):
1011
1012
1013
1014
1015
1016
              
      def retrieve_connection(spec_name) #:nodoc:
        pool = retrieve_connection_pool(spec_name)
        raise ConnectionNotEstablished, "No connection pool with '#{spec_name}' found." unless pool
        pool.connection
      end

Comment: Hey, Please check the indentation I've edited my answer