# How come my code and postgres are not connecting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql, sqlite

I am trying to change my database.yml file to postgresql.
This is an extension from my previous question [Changing sqlite to pg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57602377/changing-sqlite-to-pg?noredirect=1#comment101663083_57602377)
Hope anyone could help

I have changed my database.yml file to what my question's answer was

this is my database.yml file

```
connection: &connection
adapter: postgresql
host: localhost
port: 5432
username: postgres
password: postgres
pool: 5
timeout: 5000
min_messages: warning

development:
  <<: *connection
  database: development_db_name
test:
  <<: *connection
 database: test_db_name

production:
  <<: *connection
  database: production_db_name
```

this is the exact indentation

i am getting:

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstalblished
No connection pool with 'primary' found



vendor/cache/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:1013:in `retrieve_connection'
vendor/cache/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:118:in `retrieve_connection'
vendor/cache/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:90:in `connection'
vendor/cache/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:554:in `call'
vendor/cache/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
vendor/cache/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:98:in `run_callbacks'
vendor/cache/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
vendor/cache/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
vendor/cache/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:61:in `call'
vendor/cache/gems/web-console-3.7.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
vendor/cache/gems/web-console-3.7.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:30:in `block in call'
vendor/cache/gems/web-console-3.7.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `catch'
vendor/cache/gems/web-console-3.7.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `call'
vendor/cache/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
vendor/cache/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
vendor/cache/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
vendor/cache/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `block in tagged'
vendor/cache/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
vendor/cache/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `tagged'
vendor/cache/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
vendor/cache/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
vendor/cache/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
vendor/cache/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
vendor/cache/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
vendor/cache/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
vendor/cache/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
vendor/cache/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
vendor/cache/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:127:in `call'
vendor/cache/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
vendor/cache/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:524:in `call'
vendor/cache/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/configuration.rb:227:in `call'
vendor/cache/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/server.rb:660:in `handle_request'
vendor/cache/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/server.rb:474:in `process_client'
vendor/cache/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/server.rb:334:in `block in run'
vendor/cache/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:135:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

that is my full trace

Comment: first you must remove gem "sqlite3" from your gem file ,then make sure that you have "pg" gem , run bundle install , and restart the server

Comment: i did remove sqlite3 but that did not change anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're installed postgresql on your local env and you've started it before opening your web app

Remove `sqlite` gem, and add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile.

For postgresql database configuration, below is mine and it works

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: my_app_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: my_app_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: my_app_production
  username: freelancer
  password: <%= ENV['FREELANCER_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Reindent your code like

`connection: &connection
       adapter: postgresql
       host: localhost
       port: 5432
       username: postgres
       password: postgres
       pool: 5
       timeout: 5000`